# Enviar E-mail - Wamp e CodeIginiter

Tags: php, codeigniter, wamp

estou tentando enviar o email via localhost pelo codeiginiter. Dentro da minha pasta de libraries, criei uma pasta "PHPMailer" para colocar os aquivos do PHPMailer. Não está enviando o email, está dando o seguinte erro:

```
2015-09-24 16:53:47 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost 2015-09-24 16:53:47    CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN 2015-09-24 16:53:47    CLIENT -> SERVER: bWF0aGV1c3Zvc2FAZ21haWwuY29t 2015-09-24 16:53:48  CLIENT -> SERVER: R0BNQC5FbGVj 2015-09-24 16:53:49  SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 f19sm4787092qhc.18 - gsmtp 2015-09-24 16:53:49   SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. 2015-09-24 16:53:49 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 2015-09-24 16:53:50  SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Quando eu altero a porta para 587, da o seguinte erro:

```
2015-09-24 17:30:49 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) 2015-09-24 17:30:49    SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Baixei os arquivos do PHPMailer no [Github do projeto](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer). Busquei outros tutoriais e vi que alguns falavam que eu tinha que descomentar uma linha no **php.ini**. Esta ja foi descomentada: `extension=php_openssl.dll`.

Verifiquei alguns tutoriais também ([este](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048347/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-through-php-mailer) e [este](https://nicholasleite.wordpress.com/2013/04/10/dica-implementando-o-phpmailer-no-codeigniter/), por exemplo) para ver o que realmente estava fazendo errado. Porém, nada funciona.
Não sei se pode acrescentar também, mas estou usando o Wamp na porta 8080, porque eu estou com o IIS rodando na porta 80.

 Meu código está aqui, pra quem precisar de mais informações:

```
//Minha lib
class My_email {
  function __construct(){
    require_once('PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');
    require_once('PHPMailer/class.smtp.php');
    require_once('PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoLoad.php');
    require_once('PHPMailer/class.phpmaileroauthgoogle.php');
    require_once('PHPMailer/class.phpmaileroauth.php');
  }
}

//Meu controller
class email extends CI_Controller{
  function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('My_email');
  }

  function enviaEmail(){
   $mail = new PHPMailer();
   $mail->IsSMTP(); 
   $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; 
   $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
   $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
   $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
   $mail->Port = 465; 
   $mail->IsHTML(true);


   $mail->Username = "meuemailpessoal@gmail.com"; 
   $mail->Password = "minhasenha"; 
   $mail->SetFrom('textoo@gmail.com', 'Remetente'); 
   $mail->AddReplyTo("meuemailpessoal@gmail.com","Nome Completo"); 
   $mail->Subject = "Assunto"; 
   $mail->Body = "Corpo do e-mail em HTML.<br />";
   $mail->AltBody = "Corpo em texto puro.";
   $destino = "destinatario@gmail.com";
   $mail->AddAddress($destino, "Pessoa Lopes Leite");

   if(!$mail->Send()) {
      echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
   } else {
      echo "Mensagem enviada com sucesso!";
   }


  }
}
```

Valeu pela atenção e ajuda :)

Comment: O erro disse que falhou a autenticação ..., pode ser a senha errrada, porta errada etc.

Comment: @rray Fiz uma edição ai, da uma olhada por favor...

Comment: Estou com o mesmo problema que você, desinstalei o Xampp, liberei a porta 80 do IIS, instalei o Xampp novamente. Reiniciei a máquina e funcionou, enviei uns 5 e-mails, até o momento em que parou e estou com o mesmo problema novamente! Acompanhando o tópico aqui!

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver após 3 alterações:

1. Exclui a lib do PhpMailer, e baixei novamente outra.
2. Só deixei o `require '/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';`
3. Após a linha `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';` 
   eu inclui: `$mail->SMTPOptions = array('ssl' => array('verify_peer' => false,'verify_peer_name' => false,'allow_self_signed' => true));`

Agora está funcionando perfeitamente.

Comment: No meu caso estou usando smtsecure como tls, e a porta é a 587. Não testei com ssl pra ver se funciona.

Comment: você baixou onde? Pode editar com o link, por favor. Irei testar a sua solução amanhã.

Comment: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: Cara, eu tentei aqui e não deu. Mas fiz uma alteração que funcionou, em partes. Peguei um domínio que eu tinha e coloquei ele pra enviar o e-mail. Quando eu coloquei lá na tela, deu erro, mas enviou. Quando eu abri a caixa de e-mail de destino, o e-mail até chegou, só que chegou no spam. Normal?